# Is there a best practice for defining variables in _init_ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

Is there any good reason for the way you define object variables in an `__init__` method, should you build new variables using `self.var` or just `var`.

Does it matter? Is there a microscopic speed benefit?

Personally I prefer the latter as debatably clearer and less text. But I often see both.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.first = firstname
        self.last = lastname
        self.fullname = self.first + ' ' + self.last
```

Or:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.first = firstname
        self.last = lastname
        self.fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname
```

Comment: There is a microscopic speed benefit to using just `var`, and I would probably use that for style reasons, too.

Comment: Well, test both, the one that works is the better one.

Comment: well i always say you can be a genius at coding something magic but if your code is not readable then its bad. I prefer the second one more readable for me.

Comment: I've found [this](https://medium.com/@jacktator/dataclass-vs-namedtuple-vs-object-for-performance-optimization-in-python-691e234253b9) comparison on using `object`,`namedtuple` and `dataclass`. With dataclass you also get the benefit of type checking. It really depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Best practices questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local names are slightly faster, so `first`, not `self.first`, as the latter requires looking up the local name `self`, then looking up the attribute `first` on that object. Local variable use is highly optimised compared to all other lookups.

However, the difference is miniscule, and focusing on that is a premature optimisation. Only worry about this if you have to use the same variable loads of times in critical code.

If you ignore the performance differences, then it comes down to requirements and clarity; instance attributes can behave very differently from local variables, which can be an advantage:

- If you need to support subclasses that want to alter how `self.first` and `self.last` behave when assigned to or when accessed (using a `property`), then you'd want to use the attributes.
- Using the local parameter names on the other hand makes it clear that `fullname` is independent of how `self.first` and `self.last` behave if not simple attributes. That could be intentional.

We can't give any more specific guidelines here because attributes can easily support different use-cases from locals.

If you do need to worry about performance, use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to run a micro-benchmark:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> class PersonAttributes():
...     def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
...         self.first = firstname
...         self.last = lastname
...         self.fullname = self.first + ' ' + self.last
...
>>> class PersonLocals():
...     def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
...         self.first = firstname
...         self.last = lastname
...         self.fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname
...
>>> timeit('P("Eric", "Idle")', 'from __main__ import PersonAttributes as P')
0.5858714409987442
>>> timeit('P("Eric", "Idle")', 'from __main__ import PersonLocals as P')
0.5170505980058806
```

The above creates an instance 1 million times, at which point you'll have saved 40 milliseconds by using local names.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about nano second differences personally , I was just wondering if that would be a reason for a best practice. I guess from your answer there is no PEP guidance on this? I didn't find any.

Comment: @ZachCleary: there isn't any, because *it depends*. If `first` and `last` are properties that alter the values on setting or getting, you may have to use `self.first` and `self.last`, for example.

Comment: If you're worried about the differences incurred in lookups by the interpreter, Python may not be the right choice of language.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Python can be the right choice even if you are worried about such things *where it counts*. The Python standard library is full of such trade-offs, including assigning globals to a local name just to avoid the cost of repeated lookups.